# How often do you update Proxmox?

Tags: proxmox

I installed Proxmox three months ago, and I have a question about how often I should run commands like `apt-get update`.

On Proxmox, according to forum members' rules, I installed only the default package plus Tailscale for tunneling (https://share.cleanshot.com/WV7wqFVR).

I want Ubuntu to install security updates automatically. Is this strategy also recommended for Proxmox?
Which approach for this problem is the best?

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: `how often I should run commands like apt-get update` as often as you'd like? I do it like twice a week, just whenever I have a spare moment to check for updates for my 15 Debian systems - but this isn't proxmox since I don't use it, just in general - reminds me ... I usually do it on a Wednesday - but I do have *unattended upgrades* installed, so, security updates are always pretty much up to date without having to lift a finger

Comment: You installed Proxmox on top of Ubuntu? Really???

Answer (score 0):

How often do *I* update proxmox? Never.

How often do my hosts update themselves? Whenever they need to.

`apt install unattended-upgrades apt-listchanges`